# Clear cache in an ExtJS application

Tags: extjs

I have an app developed in ExtJS v.6.6.0, after having reinstalled XAMPP due to a hardware change I have serious cache problems that I cannot solve.
I have already cleared the cache in the browser and when I refresh the page the previous code continues to appear without the changes, I have used another browser that I never used before to enter the site, and the same old page appears ... therefore the browser doesn't the problem.
In PHP I have all the headers to avoid the cache.
In php.ini the variable opcache.enable = 0
I don't know what to do anymore, I just have to check ExtJS and see if any parameter I'm overlooking.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you run `sencha app watch`? In case you are adding new files, these might not be loaded if you did not rebuild the app. Or it might be, that you have an error in `sencha app build development`. If that happens you are not creating a new app and still run the old app.
About Chrome: Settings - deactivate Cache in Development Mode.

Comment: @Dinkheller    I tried **sencha app refresh** and **sencha app build development**, all commands appear without error, but the app.js not change and refreshing the page the older version appear again. I have a week with this problem without solution, can you help me? never before that happen to me using sencha Cmd.

Comment: please let me know how I can contact you. It is not possible to see your setup from what you added here.

Comment: @Dinkheller.   Thanks a lot, my whatsapp number is +528117005980, please, send me a message. Yesterday I installed a fresh copy of xampp in another computer, copied the projects files, and the same cache problem... I'm crazy with this.

Comment: Just curious, did you guys solve it? What was the issue? Thanks

Comment: I never knew what the problem was. I copied an older version of the app.js file and everything worked again. Now, "sencha app watch" works fine!